# Add a fade effect to my bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a three image carousel.

```
<div class="6u$ 12u$(medium) important(medium)">
<span class="image fit"><img src="screen1.png" alt="" /></span><span> class="image fit"><img src="screen2.png" alt="" /></span><span class="image fit"><img src="screen4.png" alt="" /></span></div>
```

The images are cycled using javascript:

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("image fit");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none"; 
}
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
setTimeout(carousel, 8000);}
</script>
```

I want to add something to my javascript to make the images fade in/out, or do some other transition effect. Is there a simple way to do this? I have some CSS that describes the class "image fit" but I don't think it's relevant. It only describes positioning of the images. Thank you.

Comment: You must consider transparency of element. In CSS, it may be `opacity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an example to fade a div over [here](http://codepen.io/SubhumanWasTaken/pen/qqYoNQ).
Basically give your container that contains your carousel a `opacity: 1;` in CSS. Create another class that has `opacity: 0;` that is going to be toggled using jQuery which then overwrites the original opacity value.
To achieve this use the following jQuery code:

```
$('.youTrigger').on('click', function () {
  $('.yourContainer').toggleClass('yourClassWithOpacity0');
});
```

Now you have a container that disappears if you press the trigger. To add a nice fading effect you need to add a transition to your container like this:
`transition: opacity 0.5s ease;`

Comment: Thank you. My carousel is rotated by a timer, so the .on.('click') call would not be appropriate. Is the logic the same, though?

Comment: Sure just call the toggleClass each time you want the carousel to fade in or out. The important thing in my solution is to switch out the class with the opacity of 0. It doesn't matter what kind of function falls this trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I do beleve you will be able to use jquery fading with bootstrap as bootsrap is dependent on jquery - https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: I tried a few of the methods but couldn't get it to work. Do you know how I can implement this in the Javascript above, while still keeping my Timing function intact